# c++ reading an array of objects causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, arrays, object, segmentation-fault

I've got two classes: Vector and Particle...

```
class Vector {
public:
    float x,y;
};

class Particle {
public:
    Vector* coord;
    Particle(Vector* coord)
    {
        this->coord = coord;
    };
};
```

... and an array declared like this:

```
Particle* particles [PARTICLES];
```

This is my main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Write
    int i = 0;
    do{
        particles[i] = new Particle(new Vector());
    }while(
           ++i<PARTICLES
           );
    i = 0;

    //Read
    int j = 0;
    float s = .0f,
    a = .0f;
    Vector vi = *(particles[0]->coord),
    vj = *(particles[0]->coord);
    do{
        do{
            if(i!=j){
                vi = *(particles[i]->coord);
                vj = *(particles[j]->coord); //FIXME
            }
        }while(
               ++j<PARTICLES //For values >1 throws SIGSEGV
               );
    }while(
           ++i<PARTICLES
           );

    return 0;
}
```

This throws an SIGSEGV whenever PARTICLES is >1. Commenting out that *FIXME* line makes it work without errors.

Full code here: http://codepad.org/dI2ve5Pc

Why does it fail and is there a way to fix it?

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm compiling with gpp using this command: `g++ teh_problem.cpp -o out`

Comment: The way to fix the problem is quit using manual memory management and start using `std::vector`.

Comment: Your code is very badly formatted... Can you fix that?

Comment: Why is that first `do-while` loop coded in a way that makes my head spin?  Why not simply increment `i` in the loop?  Why make it part of the `while` condition?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using c-with classes instead of c++?

Comment: You certainly should not name your class for a point coordinate `Vector`. There is a standard library class named `vector` which you should be using for your array of Particles. And you should not be using dynamic memory for the `coord` member variable. That buys you nothing but unreadability and a memory management nightmare.

Comment: I agree with PlasmaHH, you don't seem to have very "c++-ey" code... you're only making your life harder by not using standard containers.

Comment: You don't even have to use `std::vector`, literally just delete every `*` and  `new` from your code, and voila!  (except for in `char** argv`).

Comment: @RobK my class Vector represents Euclidean vector with special functions (which I omitted in this code). What other name should it have?

Comment: @MattMcNabb He needs to change the `->` dereferences to .s also. @m93a It's a point, you could call it that, or if you want to stick closer to physics terms you could call it coordinate_vector.

Comment: @RobK It's not only coord. vector. I use it for speed, forces etc. It's just vector.

Comment: You should use separate types for each of those things. I would suggest `euclidean_vector` as a base type, then perhaps derive `coordinate`, `force`, and `speed` from that type. It's best to name a thing what it is, not the generality you use to represent it. Try starting from `typedef std::pair< float, float > euclidean_vector;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop is written incorrectly. `j` is not reset before the second iteration of the inner loop. Why don't you code the loops like most people usually do:

```
for (i = 0; i < PARTICLES; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < PARTICLES; j++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember to reset `j` to `0` after every iteration of `j`'s loop:

```
 do{
  do{
   if(i!=j){
    vi = *(particles[i]->coord);
    vj = *(particles[j]->coord); //FIXME
   }
  }while(
   ++j<PARTICLES //For values >1 throws SIGSEGV
  );

  // Reset j here
  j = 0;
  ///////////////

 }while(
  ++i<PARTICLES
 );
```